# Threads for 4(or more) concurrent array sorts

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, python-multithreading

I create a code that just sorts the same array into 4 windows:

```
import pygame
  
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
canvas = pygame.Surface((800, 600))

p1_camera = pygame.Rect(0,0,400,300)
p2_camera = pygame.Rect(400,0,400,300)
p3_camera = pygame.Rect(0,300,400,300)
p4_camera = pygame.Rect(400,300,400,300)

sub1 = canvas.subsurface(p1_camera)
sub2 = canvas.subsurface(p2_camera)
sub3 = canvas.subsurface(p3_camera)
sub4 = canvas.subsurface(p4_camera)

pygame.draw.line(sub2, (255,255,255), (0,0), (0,300), 10)
pygame.draw.line(sub4, (255,255,255), (0,0), (0,300), 10)
pygame.draw.line(sub3, (255,255,255), (0,0), (400,0), 10)
pygame.draw.line(sub4, (255,255,255), (0,0), (400,0), 10)

pygame.display.set_caption("Bubble sort")

x = 40
y = 40
  
width = 20
  
height = [3, 50, 130, 90, 250, 61, 110,
            88, 33, 80, 70, 159, 180, 20]

  
run = True
  

def show(height):
    for i in range(len(height)):

        pygame.draw.rect(sub1, (255, 0, 0), (x + 25 * i, y, width, height[i]))
        pygame.draw.rect(sub2, (255, 0, 0), (x + 25 * i, y, width, height[i]))
        pygame.draw.rect(sub3, (255, 0, 0), (x + 25 * i, y, width, height[i]))
        pygame.draw.rect(sub4, (255, 0, 0), (x + 25 * i, y, width, height[i]))

        pygame.draw.line(sub2, (255,255,255), (0,0), (0,300), 10)
        pygame.draw.line(sub4, (255,255,255), (0,0), (0,300), 10)
        pygame.draw.line(sub3, (255,255,255), (0,0), (400,0), 10)
        pygame.draw.line(sub4, (255,255,255), (0,0), (400,0), 10)

        win.blit(sub1, (0,0))
        win.blit(sub2, (400, 0))
        win.blit(sub3, (0, 300))
        win.blit(sub4, (400, 300))


while run:
    execute = False
  
    pygame.time.delay(10)
  
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
  
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
  
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        execute = True
  
    if execute == False:
        win.fill((0, 0, 0))
        show(height)
  
        pygame.display.update()
  
    else:
        for i in range(len(height) - 1):
            for j in range(len(height) - i - 1):
                if height[j] > height[j + 1]:
                    t = height[j]
                    height[j] = height[j + 1]
                    height[j + 1] = t
  
                sub1.fill((0, 0, 0))
                sub2.fill((0, 0, 0))
                sub3.fill((0, 0, 0))
                sub4.fill((0, 0, 0))
  
                show(height)
                  
                pygame.time.delay(50)

                pygame.display.update()
  

pygame.quit()
```

It works fine, but my main task was to create parallel sorting threads of different arrays. But I can't imagine how to do it in pygame, because the update goes to the whole window, not just part of it.

I will be grateful for advice or help.

Answer (score 0):

The pygame.display.update() method has an optional argument that allowes you to only update part of the screen. https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update
You can define a rect that will be the only area updated.
You also tagged your question with multi threading, which can be done using this library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html
This should be everything you need.